# Transforming an Optimization Problem into a multi-vector Optimization Problem

Tags: mathematical-optimization, vector

I am sitting on an MultiAgent optimization problem trying to solve for a quadruple of variables

```
{e,l,b,c}
```

In a single agent (`n=1`) environment the optimization problem looks like this which works:

**Objective Function:**

```
f[e_?NumericQ, l_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ] := (l*1.04 + e*1.057 - b*0.8632^(-1))/(-1)
```

**Maximization:**

```
NMaximize[{f[e, l, b], 
  c >= 0.2*d[[1]] && (c + e + l - d[[1]] - b)/(e + 0.2*l) >= 0.09 && 
   c + l + e == b + W[[1]] + d[[1]] && c >= 0 && e >= 0 && l >= 0 &&
    b >= 0}, {e, l, b, c}]
```

Where `d[[1]]` and `W[[1]]` are Values drawn from `NormalDistributions`:

```
W = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[65, 10], {n, 1}]

d = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[300, 100], {n, 1}]
```

**Output:**

> {-0.00165118, {e -> 532.54, l -> 626.225, b -> 702.162, c -> 54.2522}}

**Problem:**

Now I want to expand that problem to a MulitAgent problem, let's say `n=10`. I don't know how to designate Vector properties to the variables and how to index them properly.

I tried this after clearing all variables:

**Objective Function multiple Agents**

```
F[e_?VectorQ, l_?VectorQ, b_?VectorQ] := (l*1.04 + e*1.057 - b*0.8632^(-1))/(-1);
```

**Maximization Multiple Agents**

```
Table[NMaximize[{f[e[[i]], l[[i]], b[[i]], c[[i]]],
  c[[i]] >= 0.2*d[[i]] && (c[[i]] + e[[i]] + l[[i]] - d[[i]] - b[[i]])/(e[[i]] + 0.2*l[[i]]) >= 0.09 && 
   c[[i]] + l[[i]] + e[[i]] == b[[i]] + W[[i]] + d[[i]] && c[[i]] >= 0 && e[[i]] >= 0 && l[[i]] >= 0 &&
    b[[i]] >= 0}, {e[[i]], l[[i]], b[[i]], c[[i]]}],{i,1,n}]
```

Which is basically the same Maximization as above, only trying to index it, since i hoped that Mathematica would calculate Variables `{e[[i]], l[[i]], b[[i]], c[[i]]}`, which is for every `Agent i` different due to drawings of `W` and `d` out of the Normal Distribution.

However, the indexation is not proper according to the error message:

> `Part::partd: "Part specification e[[1]] is longer than depth of object"` etc.

How can I transform this scenario in a multiple Vector Scenario?

Comment: Creating a `Table` won't help you. You need to create arrays for your individual variables like `eVars = Array[e,n]` where `n` is some fixed integer. Then you need to create an appropriate objective function, that mixes all the components together in the way you want them to interact and yield a real value, not some kind of vector. Essentially you can just optimize in ordered spaces (you need to know whats bigger and smaller).

Comment: Thanks! It worked to define the variable as arrays to create the necessary depth. The Error Message `Part::partd:` is no problem anymore

Comment: ResidentStiefel or @Wizard would either one of you consider writing this solution up as an answer, so the question does not show up as unanswered anymore? Self-answers are also encouraged on StackExchange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a Table won't help you.
You need to create an array (list) for your individual variables like

```
eVars = Array[e,n]
```

where `n` is some fixed integer.

Then you need to create an appropriate objective function, that mixes all the components together in the way you want them to interact and yield a real value, not some kind of vector.

From a mathematical standpoint: Essentially you can just optimize in ordered spaces (you need to know whats bigger and smaller).